# Removed widget remains on parent

Tags: kivy

I have parent window that is `Widget` where places another widgets (`parent.add_widget(...)`) by right mouse click. Also children widget can be removed by middle click (`parent.remove_widget(...)`). And here I faced strange issue - child actually removed from `children` collection of `parent` but remains visible (but inactive. i.e. all interactions with removed widget image are impossible). I do not using any layouts because children are movable to any point and thus should not be aligned somehow.

Question: how to redraw parent after `remove_widget`?

Example code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.behaviors import DragBehavior
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout


Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,disable_multitouch')


Builder.load_string(f'''
<Node@RelativeLayout>:
    drag_rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
    drag_timeout: 10000000
    drag_distance: 10

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.bcolor
        RoundedRectangle:
            pos: 0, 0
            size: self.size
            radius: [10,]
''')


class Node(DragBehavior, RelativeLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.bcolor = (0, 0, 1, 1)
        super(Node, self).__init__(size=(100, 100), **kwargs)

    def placement_pos(self, x, y):
        return (x - self.node_width() / 2, y - self.node_height() / 2)


Builder.load_string(f'''
<GrapherUI@Widget>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: {.5, 1, .5, 1}
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
''')


class GrapherUI(Widget):
    def __init__(self, graph=None, **kwargs):
        super(GrapherUI, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        touched_children = [x for x in self.walk(restrict=True) if x is not self and x.collide_point(*touch.pos)]

        has_touched_children = any(touched_children)

        if touch.button == 'right':
            if not has_touched_children:
                self.add_node(touch)
        elif touch.button == 'middle':
            self.remove_node(touched_children, touch)

        super(GrapherUI, self).on_touch_down(touch)

    def add_node(self, touch):
        print('add node')
        with self.canvas:
            node = Node(pos=(touch.x, touch.y))
            self.add_widget(node)

    def remove_node(self, touched_children, touch):
        for node in touched_children:
            print('remove node')
            self.remove_widget(node)


class Main(App):
    def build(self):
        return GrapherUI()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main().run()
```

Comment: This shouldn't happen, so there isn't a specific function call you're intended to make to correct it. It could be a bug in your code, or in Kivy. Post a minimal runnable example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @inclement added example code. On main canvas right click new draggable widget instantiated. When perform middle click on widget - it removed an stops responding on drag events (so I suppose it is removed) but still visible on canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as usual with Kivy nobody except yourself could help  (even documentation). Here issue caused by `with self.canvas:` line under `add_node` method. If it removed widget disappears after removing.

Comment: This saved me after two days of searching! I've been adding the Labels to the parent in the `with self.canvas:` block, which make the children to be shown even though they were removed. Once the code is moved outside the block, removal of children (the Labels) causes them to disappear as one would expect.